# Git blame with wildcard

Tags: git, wildcard, msysgit

I have a file in my repository I want to use git blame on, but I'm not sure what its path is.

I've managed to use git log like this:

```
git log -- '**/somefile'
```

But I can't seem to do the same with git blame. Is it possible?

If it's relevant, I'm using mysysgit (git version: 1.9.5.msysgit.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to find the file first:

```
git ls-files -- '**/somefile'
```

Then use `git blame` on the returned path.

Comment: `git ls-files -- '**/somefile' | xargs git blame`
Should be the best solution.

Comment: `git blame` doesn't accept multiple files, if you're using it with `xargs` you need to tell it to just pass one file at a time: `git ls-files -- '**/somefile' | xargs -n1 git blame`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in Bash on OS X:

```
git blame -- **/foo.json
```

I had to leave off the quotes for it to work...

Comment: That's a shell expansion, unrelated to git.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
I get an error: "fatal: no such path '**/somefile' in HEAD

Comment: You probably don't have it enabled you can check with `shopt globstar`

Comment: The double-star glob expansion takes place when 1) the two stars are _unquoted_ and 2) `globstar` is enabled as @MatthewBuckett said. The result is: if one or more files match the glob, the glob argument is replaced with all the matched files (each one is separated with a space I think), or, if no file matched the glob, the argument is unchanged, which explains the error `fatal: no such path '**/somefile' in HEAD` that the OP got: no file was matched by the shell expansion, so Git literally received `**/somefile` as argument, which Git couldn't find either.